# NodeJs y MSSQL query a un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: nodejs, stored-procedure, mssql

realice este procedimiento almacenado que probé en el motor de base de datos y esta funcionando:

identify 'rastafinis',

básicamente así se ejecuta en el MSSQM

este es el código del prendimiento almacenado

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[identify]
    @Name VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    select * from AccountsDB.dbo.MEMB_INFO where memb___id = @Name
END
GO
```

intente llamar este procedimiento usando nodejs

```
                    const sql =                     require('mssql')


                    let z
                    const sqlConfig = {
                    user            : a.user,
                    password        : a.pass,
                    database        : a.db,
                    server          : a.host,
                    pool: {
                      max: 10,
                      min: 2,
                      idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
                    },
                    options: {
                      encrypt: false, // for azure
                      trustServerCertificate: false // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs
                    }
                }

                const po2 = new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlConfig)

                po2.on('error', function(err) {
                    console.error(err);
                })
                po2.connect(function (err, z) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }
                console.log('Connected as id ' + z)
                z = z
            })

const result = await z.request()
                    .input('Name', a.c.user)
                    .execute(`dbo.MUO_identify`).then(function(err, recordsets, returnValue, affected) {
                        console.log(recordsets); return
                        // console.dir(err);
                    }).catch(function(err) {
                        console.log(err); return 
                    })
```

pero no tengo resultado ni algún error.
comprobé que si hace la conexión pero no realiza la consulta del procedimiento almacenado.
ayúdenme por favor.

ya lo encontré en verdad si esta trayendo los resultados pero estoy manejando el colbac de la función. **err, recordsets, returnValue, affected**

esta retornando todo en un solo objeto que tiene matrices en el interior con los nombres **recordsets y recordset**

de manera que solo cambie esto

```
.execute(`dbo.MUO_identify`).then(function(err, recordsets, returnValue, affected)`...
```

por esto

```
.execute(`dbo.MUO_identify`).then(function(resuts)
```

Answer (score 0):

cambie esto

```
.execute(`dbo.MUO_identify`).then(function(err, recordsets, returnValue, affected)`...
```

por esto

```
.execute(`dbo.MUO_identify`).then(function(resuts)
```